# Do I need to secure a GET-only backed REST API for a SPA

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, authorization, single-page-application

I have a JavaScript SPA which consumes a backend REST API built with Django (Django Rest Framework). It's a small academic project which is likely to attract only a few hundred users on a regular basis. Our initial design assumed that users might wish to save data, but recent consultation with potential clients has made us question whether we need to incorporate this feature. So this would completely remove any need for POST requests to the backend API, leaving only GETs. These GETs (via axios) contain only path parameters, no query params, and return small JSON payloads, used to render SVG components in the application (this data is read-only, static data, already stored in the backend db).

The assumed need to cater for user uploads led us to also add user login/logout and account management features. We even started to look at integrating Auth0. But if we remove user upload entirely do we even need to secure our API endpoints in this way?

Comment: do you still have data that only some users may see or not? If yes you need authentication. I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Thanks. The backend db already has data in it. This is read-only, it never changes. It's a music project, the data is used to render musical scores. This would all be public, we wouldn't need to hide any of this. Previously we had assumed that our users would want to save edits to their own scores, but this now seems unlikely.

Comment: if you don't need to restrict permissions then you don't need authentication. why would you need it, and what would it do. if the answer is "nothing" you don't need it.

Comment: Do a whitelist in your backend REST API only allowing to retrieve data from the IP of the SPA and for only retrieving GET calls you wouldn't need authentication.

Answer (score 0):

From what's given in the OP, answer is, **No**, you do not need authentication.

Irrespective of the HTTP verb used, just ask yourself, whatever functionality you are exposing through your REST apis, at least, do you care to find out who did what using your APIs? if not you don't need Authentication

Basically,

1. Do you want to restrict access to any APIs?
2. Do you want to tie an action to any persona?
3. Do you want to audit, (who did what when)?

If answer to all these 3 is **no**, you do not need authentication.